# Using an IoC framework, I need to get a value from an injected class to an extension method

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I've got a fairly small website I'm working on, and I've reached a point where I need to convert my absolute paths to relative path in my html.  I'm using AutoFac for my IoC, and I build a wrapper to inject my web.config app settings throughout my project and have run into a wall with this bit:

I have a config value called "ContentServerPath" which my wrapper takes care of to pass on:

```
public interface IConfigurationWrapper
{
    string ContentServerPath { get; }
}
```

and my implementation (fairly straightforward):

```
public ConfigurationWrapper()
        : this(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
    {
    }


    internal ConfigurationWrapper(NameValueCollection appSettings, ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connectionStrings)
    {
        ContentServerPath = appSettings["ContentServerPath"];
    }
```

My _layout.cshtml page has been initially coded to use local stylesheets and jquery while the site was being developed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/assets/styles/site.css" />
```

The final output I was hoping to do was to replace the html line with something along the lines of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Html.GetContentPath("assets/styles/site.css")" />
```

However, it's proving to be a horrendous task due to the fact that when I call the extension method, I cannot inject my IConfigurationWrapper into the static class.

My initial thought was something along the lines of

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetContentPath(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string relativeContentPath)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/{1}", _configuration.ContentServerPath, relativeContentPath);
    }
```

but, again, I cannot inject the configuration wrapper into the static method.

As a side note, the reason I have put the content path into the web.config is because we have several different test environments, each requiring it's own config values for content.  We rely on xdt transforms for our build server to pick up any changes before deploying code and modify the config accordingly.

Anyone run into something like this before and have a good solution?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider allowing the context of `HtmlHelperExtensions` to specify the dependency:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetContentPath(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string relativeContentPath)
    {
        EnsureWrapper();

        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("{0}/{1}", ConfigurationWrapper.ContentServerPath, relativeContentPath));
    }

    public static IConfigurationWrapper ConfigurationWrapper;

    private static void EnsureWrapper()
    {
        if(ConfigurationWrapper == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, set it in the composition root:

```
HtmlHelperExtensions.ConfigurationWrapper = container.Resolve<IConfigurationWrapper>();
```

This is a solid pattern when another library mandates a static class, amounting to static dependency inversion. It imposes a minimal amount of infrastructure knowledge, similar to constructor injection for instances.

You can take it a step further and cut out the middleman, simplifying `HtmlHelperExtensions` and externalizing as much detail as possible:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetContentPath(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string relativeContentPath)
    {
        EnsureContentServerPath();

        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("{0}/{1}", ContentServerPath, relativeContentPath));
    }

    public static string ContentServerPath;

    private static void EnsureContentServerPath()
    {
        if(EnsureContentServerPath == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after several more hours of research, I ended up using the dependency resolver in my extension to get the configuration value I was looking for:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetContentPath(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string relativeContentPath)
    {
        return GetContentPath(relativeContentPath, AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.ApplicationContainer.Resolve<IConfigurationWrapper>());
    }

    internal static MvcHtmlString GetContentPath(string relativeContentPath, IConfigurationWrapper configuration)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(string.Format("{0}/{1}", configuration.ContentServerPath, relativeContentPath););
    }
}
```

Hopefully this at least helps someone else down the road!

-Troggy

Comment: You should set the standard MVC DependencyResolver using an AutofacDependencyResolver and then just do DependencyResolver.Current instead of directly accessing the application container. It's best practice to avoid resolving components directly out of the container whenever possible.